# Blender Game animation recording: specific recording

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am currently working on a simulation where I want a pillar to be destroyed by a sphere, when I click on record animation and run it, the sphere does not move.

How do I prevent this from happening so my sphere's animation is not overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the [`record_animation`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.record_animation) property to `False` for the ball object:

```
cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
cont.owner.record_animation = False
```